# Usage of jquery noConflict : Assert my Understanding

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Webpage which has jquery library , my js and 3rd party library.

```
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/webPage.js"></script>
<script src="/thirdParty.js"></script>
```

webPage.js contains all the bindings for click events for the Web Page using

```
$("button").on('click',...) etc
```

The third party library uses the following line of code

```
if(window.jQuery) 
   var jcb = jQuery.noConflict();
```

`jcb` is then used for doing simple tasks like `append , select etc`

the moment the code executes the above line , `$  goes for a toss and I get the error - Error "$ is not a function".`

If I block the Third party library - the page works

Is the above usage correct ? They should not have used the Above code snippet at all. Rather this :

```
if(window.jQuery) 
       jcb = window.jQuery;
```

**`OR`**

In my JS file i should something like `window.jQuery123=$.noConflict();` and not bother about the third party library

Which approach is correct ?

Answer (score 3):

By default, whenever somwhere `jQuery.noConflict();` is called, the `$` is not available anymore (*for more details what it does, take a look at the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)*). From now on only `jQuery`, or in your example `jcb`, is the only way to access jQuery.

```
jQuery("selector").html(); // works
test("selector").html();   // works NOT
$("selector").html();      // works

var test = jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery("selector").html(); // works
test("selector").html();   // works
$("selector").html();      // works NOT
```

You can wrap other code with an `IIFE` or `closure` to let it work with `$` again:

```
(function($) {
    $("selector").html();
})(jQuery);
```

You can even regiester the `$` again by yourself. But that could have side effects with your third party apps, when something is using the `$` by it's own.

```
window.$ = jQuery;
```

Comment: Since its a third party code - i would not know which variable to use - its ideally a blackbox for me. For finding RCA i have debugged this code and found the issue. The question is - since this is blackbox how to resolve this ? If i add more libraries (vendor) i cannot keep on debugging stuff like this ..

Comment: Just use `jQuery`. You don't need to know what they use as a name, because `jQuery` will be available as variable too. @user1428716

Comment: statement about noConflict **always** removing `$` is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, true. Was a bit uncelar. Added a note. Thx, @charlietfl

Comment: let me try IIFE

Comment: now you have modified your answer so much that initial statements are still inaccurate...not to mention you put the IIFE in based on my answer

Comment: What are you talking about? And I had the `IIFE` example in before. To be exactly, I had two `IIFE` examples in before, but to be clear I remove a too complex example with `test`. See the history. And *your answer* don't need to be copied. It is so simple, really. :D @charlietfl

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your code in :

```
(function( $ ) {
  $(function() {
    // your code here
  });
})(jQuery);
```

the 3rd party library will not impact your use of `$` inside the IIFE since it isn't the global `window.$`, it is an isolated local instance

Alternatively the 3rd party library should be using `noConflict(true)` so as not to interfere with other uses of `$`. I would report this as a bug in their library

Comment: I added noConflict(true) - it doesnt work - let me try IIFE

Comment: You should not make changes in third party libs. This will break on updates or somthing. Only change your own code! @user1428716

Comment: @eisbehr - true that - intention is to point the vendor about the error

Comment: Because you seems to like to correct other people, two other points about your answer: First, without knowing the code it's a bad idea to add a `ready state` by default inside the `IIFE`. Explain the reason or remove it, because the OP meight not know what he does there. Second, it is not a isolated `local instance`, it's just another `scope`. You're still using the same instance of jQuery inside the `IIFE` as on the outside.

Comment: @eisbehr $ is local inside the IIFE .. that instance of $ is unavailable outside the IIFE

Comment: Yes, it's a local scope, but not a local instance. Better said, a `reference` to a `local scope` of an `global instance`.

Answer (score 0):

Calling $.noConflict(**true**) from the second version will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first version.